# NSMutable array counting objects of specific type

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have NSMutableArray full of objects of two different types. I need to find out number of objects of certain type. Does exist some function like count to count objects of specific type, or I have to iterate through array and count them manually?

Thank you.

Comment: 1 step: filter by type. 2 step - take count of filtered array;

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSInteger *countTypeA;
NSInteger *countTypeB;
for (id object in array) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[firstType class]]) {
        countTypeA++;
    } else if ([object isKindOfClass:[secondType class]]){
        countTypeB++;
    }
}
```